# PHP foreach in foreach problem

Tags: php, foreach

I want to insert some value from first and second foreach into database, but I met some trouble. I write my problem in the code. I can not solve the two loop problem. I ask for a help.

```
<?php
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
set_time_limit(0);
require_once ('../conn.php'); 
require_once ('../simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=large&q=obama&key={api-key}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($body);
foreach ($data->responseData->results as $result) { 
$title = html_entity_decode($result->titleNoFormatting);
$link = html_entity_decode($result->unescapedUrl);
$html = @file_get_html($link );
foreach(@$html->find('h3') as $element) {
     $table=$element;
         echo $table;// here while the $table is empty, echo is null.  
}
echo $table;// here while the $table is empty, echo will repeat the prev $table value.  
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO ...");// I want insert all the $title and $table into database.
} 
echo '<hr />';
}
?>
```

I print the result `while the $table is empty, echo will repeat the prev $table value`.

```
Organizing for America | BarackObama.com

Barack Obama - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

President Barack Obama | The White House
President Obama Nominates William Francis Kuntz, II to the United States District Court//the prev value

Change.gov - The Official Web Site of the
President Obama Nominates William Francis Kuntz, II to the United States District Court//here the $table is empty, it will repeat the prev $table value, and it should be empty.

Barack Obama on Myspace
Idle Friends▼

ob (obama) on Twitter
Piè di pagina

Barack Obama
Advertise with the NY Daily News!

Barack Obama on the Issues
Voting Record
```

Comment: No question here, or am I wrong? Just see a bunch of code.

Comment: So, what's your problem?  What's happening that shouldn't or what's not happening that should?

Comment: @Rocket, if I want to insert into database, I will use the second `echo $table;`(in the first foreach loop). but as I print the result, the second  `President Obama Nominates William Francis Kuntz, II to the United States District Court// here the $table should be empty, but it will repeat the prev $table value and echo out.` this is not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP's variable initialization and scoping rules are kind of funny.

At no point are you *initializing* `$table`.  It first gets referenced two `foreach`es deep.  PHP allows this, and won't complain about it.

The problem is that you're constantly trying to set it to a value, but you're *never actually resetting it*.

Initialize it to `null` before the inner `foreach`:

```
$html = file_get_html($link );
$table = null;  // <-- New!
foreach($html->find('h3') as $element) {
     $table = $element;
     echo $table;
}
```

This ensures that, when the `foreach` is completed, `$table` will either be `null`, or it will be the final H3 element in the HTML document you fetched.  (Incidentally, if you really did want the final H3, you can probably just grab the array that `find` returns and look at the last element rather than looping through.)

Also, please get rid of the `@` error-silencing operators, turn `error_reporting` all the way up, and make sure you've turned on `display_errors`.  You may have other errors lurking that you are *intentionally* ignoring, and that leads to horror stories.

Comment: Great, You solved my problem, thank you very much. Now the result will not repeat the prev value. :}

Comment: `$html = @file_get_html($link);` In this, I want to avoid if the $link is not a html link, like rss ,pdf. so the `file_get_html($link);` will error, then stop the whole php script. I think if it is not a real html link, the `$table` insert into a empty value into a database.

Comment: Surely there is a better way to determine this information rather than suppress the error?  `file_get_html` simply does a `file_get_contents`, then loads the resulting string into a new Simple HTML DOM object.  You can perform that step yourself, detecting HTML before creating the object.